# WordPress theme, white space to the right

Tags: css, wordpress, scroll, margins

I've been looking for a solution, but haven't come up with anything so far.

I am building my site on wordpress. Everything is going fine, but I have a margin on the entire body on the right. You are able to scroll to the right and see where my header cuts off and there is a white margin. it does not do that with the admin bar at the top, only my theme body. I didn't add any margins to the body, the width is 100%. Anyone have an idea or a link with a solution? I'ved looked at it on a different computers and browsers and it does the same thing.

here is my website (work in progress)

http://www.thewaymultimedia.com/wordpress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be your `footer` element.  It has a width of 100% and also has left-right padding.  If you make padding style on this element `padding: 10px 0px` the problem goes away.

Comment: You are my hero Mike. Thanks. Any guidance on where my logic was going wrong?

Comment: There is no logic error.  You will just have this happen if you are trying to use 100% width item with padding. The items width is 100% the size of what it can grow to, then the padding makes the item 100% + 40px (20px on each side) in your specific case).  I think a better understanding of the box model would help. See this link for more info:  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp